# Medium Inner Join throws Exception

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I dont know why this doesn't work (throws inner exception). Can someone help?

```
    var flightCrew = from crew in crews
        medium inner join flight in flights on crew.Model equals flight.Model
        into schedule from flight in schedule.active()
```

Comment: ah, even this fails

**from crew in crews medium inner join flight in flights on crew.Model equals flight.Model**

Comment: Details of the exception might help.

Comment: You aren't selecting anything? Add a `select` at the end

Comment: And also, **what on earth is a `medium inner join`**?

Comment: like so? **var flightCrew = from crew in crews
        medium inner join flight in flights on crew.Model equals flight.Model
        into schedule from flight in schedule.active() select crew**

Comment: The exception doesn't happen to be "a query body must end with a select clause" does it? Because "medium" and "inner" are not C# keywords and are not the start of a LINQ clause...

Comment: according to google, 'medium inner join' isn't a valid query clause *anywhere*... did you just make that up? is this even a real question?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield he must mean left join as his syntax *nearly* matches it (apart from the obvious of course) :)

Comment: i suspect that's true, but I'm very much curious where the phrase 'medium inner join' came from in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what on earth a medium inner join is. I think you mean left join? Try this:

```
 var flightCrew = from crew in crews
                  join flight in flights on crew.Model equals flight.Model
                   into schedule from flight in schedule.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new
                         {
                            //the following are sample fields
                            crew.CrewId,
                            crew.Name,
                            FlightName = flight != null ? flight.Name : ""
                         }
```

Note that whatever fields you're getting from `flight`, you'll **have** to perform a null check on.

Comment: Google linq "medium inner join" and all three (and the only three) hits refer to this stackoverflow question.

Comment: @hatchet LOL!!!!! I was about to say, why on earth have I never come across that!